# Particulate solution for $y''(x)-3y'(x)=2x+1+e^{3x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am in the process of solving this differential equation: $$y''(x)-3y'(x)=2x+1+e^{3x}$$

I have the homogeneous solution. However, I am not getting anywhere with the particular solution.

One of the homogeneous solutions is $e^{3x}$, which is why we would multiply an $x$ to it in the particulate approach. However, the other homogeneous solution is $1$ and I don't know exactly how it works.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Use "superposition principle"

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Three ways:

1. Let $w=y'$ so you reduce it to a first order differential equation $w'-3w=x+1+e^{3x}$
2. Use the method called "Undetermined Coefficients". Here is a link:
   https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/undeterminedcoefficients.aspx
   This is a standard method to find particular solutions under some conditions. You can see the table in this link, and it helps organize those cases.
3. Use the method called "Variation of Parameters". Here is a link:
   https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/VariationofParameters.aspx
   This is also a standard method to find particular solutions, and it is much more powerful than method #2.

Answer (score 3):

$$y''(x)-3y'(x)=2x+1+e^{3x}$$
Multiply by $e^{-3x}$:
$$(y'(x)e^{-3x})'=2xe^{-3x}+e^{-3x}+1$$
Integrate both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Your homogenous equation $y''-3y'=0$ has characteristic equation $r^2-3r=0$ with roots $r=0$ and $r=3$.

Whose general solution is $y_h=C_1e^{0x}+C_2e^{3x}=C_1+C_2e^{3x}$

Now to find particular solutions you need to consider this recipe:

> - your homogeneous equation has root $b$ with multiplicity $m$ (convention $m=0$ if $b$ is not a root)
> - the full equation has a RHS of the form $P(x)e^{bx}$ with $P$ polynomial.
>
> Then you need to search for a particular solution in the form
> $Q(x)e^{bx}$ with $Q$ polynomial and $$\deg(Q)=\deg(P)+m$$
>
> Although since the homogeneous solution will already have vanishing
> terms $(C_0+C_1x+\cdots+C_{m-1}x^{m-1})e^{bx}$, you can ignore them in
> the polynomial Q.
>
> In case of a linear combination of such terms in the RHS, you can also
> search for a linear combination of particular solutions for each.
>
> *Note: in the special case of $RHS = P(x)$, consider the root $b=0$ since $e^{0x}=1$, and the same rule applies.*

Your right hand side is $RHS=\underbrace{(2x+1)}_\text{degree 1}\times e^{0x}+\underbrace{1}_\text{degree 0}\times e^{3x}$

Since both $0$ and $3$ are roots with multiplicity $1$ you need to search for a particular solution where the degree of the polynomial is raised by $1$ for both.

Therefore $y_p=(ax^2+bx+c)+(dx+e)e^{3x}$

Note that to simplify the calculation we can ignore $c$ and $e$ as they will cancel (solution of homogeneous equation already).

So search for $y_p=(ax^2+bx)+dxe^{3x}$, report in the ODE, and equate the coefficients to the desired RHS.